# How can I display a nav title and static text on the same line so that the text is on the right and title on the left?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap. My code looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class='container-fluid'>
<div class="navbar-header">
<?php
echo "<a href='index.php' class='navbar-brand'>Title</a>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>";
echo "<li><p class='navbar-text'>(Logged in as " . $_SESSION['logged_user'] . ".)</p>";
echo "</ul></div></nav>\n";
```

Something is causing a line break between the title and the text on the right. If the text is a link and not static text, then it displays on the same line like in w3schools example. Removing the p tag doesn't help, it just makes the text change color and become almost impossible to read. If I extend the navbar-header tag to encompass the static text, that moves the static text to the left. I just want to get rid of the line break. I don't want to turn the text into a link to nowhere or a button that does nothing. I just want it to be text on the same line as the header.

Comment: Looks like I forgot the closing tag for <li> *headdesk*

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/c7erubps/

Comment: I'm starting to think that the line break probably comes from css for p as basic because there is another style that is applied. If I use the code in the editor without any other css, there is no line break.

Answer (score 0):

`Div` is a block level element by default so it will take the whole width.

Just in the same line? a simple example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class="row">
      <a href='index.php' class='navbar-brand'>Title</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p class='navbar-text'>Logged in as test</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

> REF of bs v3.3.7 source code:

```
.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}



// Navbar nav
//
// Custom navbar navigation (doesn't require `.nav`, but does make use of `.nav-link`).

.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; // cannot use `inherit` to get the `.navbar`s value
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;

  .nav-link {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: The static text is supposed to be aligned to the right. I can make it work in an online editor but if I copy the same code to my computer, something inserts a line break. So the problem must be in my end.

Comment: Turns out I had clear:both on ul. I couldn't initially find it with search for some reason, so I scrolled through line by line until I found it.

Comment: lol Just as I got them on the same line, another navbar started centering its contents at random. I don't think removing the clear:both should have anything to do with that. This is so ridiculous all I can do is laugh.

Comment: Also something is turning the text inside buttons and selects gray, so that you can hardly read it. But this is a whole 'nother topic.